# Error in maven-failsafe-plugin during parallel tests running

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm have a working application and it runs integration tests without any problems.
I want to run it in parallel and added

`<parallel>classes</parallel>
<useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>`

to maven-failsafe-plugin section in pom file.

As a result this section looks like this

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/IntegrationTestSuite.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*Tests.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <parallel>classes</parallel>
                        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

It runs tests but in the end of running I'm getting the error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:integration-test (default) on project pr: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:integration-test failed: There was an error in the forked process org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4RunListener.rethrowAnyTestMechanismFailures(JUnit4RunListener.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:109)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:78)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:54)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:144)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.ConcurrentRunListener.testStarting(ConcurrentRunListener.java:129)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4RunListener.testStarted(JUnit4RunListener.java:91)
at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testStarted(SynchronizedRunListener.java:49)
at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$3.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:121)
at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestStarted(RunNotifier.java:118)
at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitScenarioReporter.beforeStory(JUnitScenarioReporter.java:100)
at org.jbehave.core.reporters.DelegatingStoryReporter.beforeStory(DelegatingStoryReporter.java:72)
at org.jbehave.core.reporters.ConcurrentStoryReporter.beforeStory(ConcurrentStoryReporter.java:117)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.perform(PerformableTree.java:790)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.performCancellable(PerformableTree.java:422)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.perform(PerformableTree.java:393)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:292)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end solution is like this:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <CPU_NUMBER_MULTIPLIER_FOR_NUMBER_OF_THREADS_IN_TEST_SUITE_RUNNER>1
                            </CPU_NUMBER_MULTIPLIER_FOR_NUMBER_OF_THREADS_IN_TEST_SUITE_RUNNER>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/IntegrationTestSuite.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*Tests.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

together with custom runner from [here](https://github.com/centic9/commons-test/tree/master/src/test/java/com/mycila/sandbox/junit/runner)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if this is going to work.

But it seems that JUnit fails if there's is a parenthesis in some test scenario description. Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/960).

So, try to remove every parenthesis "()" from your tests descriptions and run again. Again, I'm not sure if this is going to work. Hope it helps you.

Comment: unfortunately not my case